# How can I provide a better resolution of uploaded pictures created with the document class standalone?

Tags: support, images

Very often I  use the document class `standalone` to created a cropped PDF for uploading to tex.stackexchange. However the resolution after the upload isn't very good. What can I do?

Comment: Convert to `.png` yourself?

Comment: @JosephWright: Andrew provided a nice solution in the chat. So I asked this question ;-)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The PDF to PNG conversion of imgur isn't very good and results in a poor resolution. You should convert it yourself to a PNG (no JPGs please!).

Note that the `standalone` class (v1.0) supports conversion to PNG. It works well with Image Magick under Linux, but isn't really tested under Windows by me.
It needs the `-shell-escape` compiler switch to call `convert` internally.

You can enable conversion using the `convert` class options.
There are settings for the size and density as well.

E.g. use:

```
\documentclass[convert={png,size=630,density=300}]{standalone}
```

to create a 630px wide PNG with 300dpi. Note that 630px is the maximal width for images in stackexchange posts. Beyond that, they will be zoomed-down. Put the `density` higher for smaller content. The `size` will resize the image, so the final density might be different.

I actually planned a special TeX.SX / Stackexchange mode, which sets suitable parameters automatically, but never implemented it.

If you have issues making this work (especially under untested OSs) than run Image Magick `convert` manually:

```
convert -density <density> <FILE>.pdf -resize <SIZEX>x<SIZEY> -quality 90 <FILE>.png
```

The `quality` setting here is just used for the PNG compression and has no other effect on this loss-less format. The `x<SIZEY>` is optional.
Note that under MS Windows there already is a `convert` executable (by Microsoft) which is for converting FAT32 hard drives to NTFS. So either the full path to Image Magick must be given or its `convert` should be renamed to `imgconvert`. Actually under Windows `standalone` will use `imgconvert` to not accidentally convert your hard drives ;-)

Comment: Your class becomes better and better ;-)

Comment: It's worth checking if the zooming down is only when the image is displayed in a post or is a real zooming down.  If not real then it can be worth uploading a higher resolution as clicking on the image loads it in a new window at full resolution.

Answer (score 12):

There can be reasons why it is useful to have a command-line method to convert PDFs to PNGs instead of letting TeX do everything - for example, if producing the PDF takes a *long* time and you don't know what resolution you want, starting again from the PDF is easier than starting again from the original TeX file.  Anyway, for those occasions the `netpbm` library is the Swiss Army Knife of command-line image manipulation for Linux/Unix.  For converting a PDF to a PNG, the command is:

```
pdftoppm -scale-to 500 letter-shapes-test-crop.pdf|pnmtopng > madman.png
```

(bonus points for guessing which answer this was used for)

Comment: Let me guess: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/51462/5239 ;-)

Comment: Two clarifications: `pdftoppm` comes with `poppler-utils` while `pnmtopng` comes with `netpbm`.

Answer (score 7):

I suspect the poor resolution you are talking about might be poor antialiasing. This is the `convert` one-liner you want:

```
convert -density 384 mwe.pdf -resize 25% mwe.png
```

### Explanation

Standard monitor resolution is 96 dots per inch, so simply sampling the pdf at 96 dpi produces a PNG image equal in size to PDF image on your screen.

```
# this looks ugly
convert -density 96 mwe.pdf mwe.png
```

Unfortunately, if you do this you'll get horribly jagged edges on your letter. Because each pixel is only one sample, a pixel that falls half on a letter and half off it will either be either black (an ugly bump on the letter) or white (an ugly bite). Goodbye, smooth edges. The solution is anti-aliasing, by oversampling the image and then shrinking it.

1. We sample at density 96 * 4 = 384 dpi;

   - This creates a four-times-as-large PNG.
2. We scale this PNG down 25 %;

   - Now the value of each pixel is the average of 16 subsamples, instead of just one. As a result, the edges of letters look smooth instead of pixelated.

#### Example of (4x4)->1 oversampling

```
convert -density $((96 * 4)) mwe-khatt.pdf -resize 25% mwe-khatt-per4.png
```

[image: 4x4 oversampling]

#### Example of 1->1 sampling

```
convert -density $((96 * 1)) mwe-khatt.pdf mwe-khatt-per1.png
```

[image]

#### Source code of the example

```
\setupbodyfont[schola, 12pt]

\startTEXpage[width=10cm, offset=3mm]
    \section{\CONTEXT}

    \input khatt-en
\stopTEXpage
```

Comment: Example images added. And you're right, dpi is 96 — 72 is the number of Adobe points per inch. (*Evil incheses! Hates them, we does!*)

Comment: OK, thanks. As information: Here, in first example image the font appears slightly, but noticeable bolder (“here” means a Windows system with 96 dpi and TFT screen).

Comment: TeX Gyre Schola is quite a bold font, so the upper image is more correct. In the lower image: notice that where the letters are thin – like the bridge of the `r`, and the vertical strokes of the `s`, – the stroke is distorted or even broken; or, in the case of bridge of the `h` of the last 'the', there is a bit of a wart on the underside. Note also the distorted x-height of the `n` in the first 'ibn'. Computer/Latin Modern, with its many thin strokes, gets mangled even worse if you don't anti-alias.

Comment: So my impression is right _(hint: I intentionally used “As information” ;-) )_.

Comment: Not critical, but I believe 96 * 4 = 38**4** dpi:) Also, a great and illustrative answer!

Comment: Thanks, @andselisk, for your kind words and sharp eyes. I've corrected the error. :-)